# Best tool for github and gitlab for Microsoft .net application

Tags: github

Please suggest best tool for committing the changes github and gitlab for C# .net applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the editors today already have git integration. Visual Studio Code has a simple [extension](https://visualstudio.github.com/) so you could describe that as "the best tool" (if you work with VS at the moment and would like to have similar UI). [Atom](https://atom.io/) has native Git integration, for Sublime there is an [extension](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Git) as well.

Alternatively you could use the [command line version of Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) (recommended) or you could download a desktop client like [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) which is a beginner friendly UI for Git. Alternatives here would be [Sublime Merge](https://www.sublimemerge.com/) which integrates neatly with Sublime Text or [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/git-client).

These tools are cross platform and freely available at the time of writing.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Please suggest some link for Command line

Comment: You can download git [here](https://git-scm.com/download/win) and use the standard git commands. If you don´t know them, there is a good documentation [i.e. here](https://git-scm.com/) and many helping pages on the internet. @Rajkumar

Comment: @Rajkumar did this help you? Could you accept this as the answer or write what you did in a separate answer?